# How can I exclude factors containing a certain symbol form matching my pattern

Tags: pattern-matching

Ok, I give up. I can't figure how to tell Mathematica to do replacement using a pattern except for some special case. Easier to explain with small example.

I want to change  pattern `Exp[any_. c]` to `c`  for all cases of pattern `any` except when `any` happened to be contain the literal symbol `x` anywhere in it.

So `Exp[5 c]` will be replaced to `c` and so will `Exp[y c]` but for `Exp[x c]` or `Exp[Sin[x] c]` I want no replacement to happen since the term multiplying `c` has `x` in it.

I am trying to use `Except` but can't get it to work.  This is what I tried

This does not work

```
ClearAll[x,c]
Exp[ x c] /. Exp[any_. c]:> c
```

So I need a way to set a pattern which says anything except `x`. So tried

```
Exp[ x  c] /.  Exp[Alternatives[Except[x], any1_.]  c] :> c
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It changed it to `c`, so pattern matched.

Do I need to use `Verbatim` in pattern for this? How?

I reached my limit in pattern matching skills in Mathematica so I need help :)

Comment: Maybe `Exp[any_. c] /; FreeQ[any, x] :> c`

Comment: @Coolwater nice! It seems to work. Will test it more. Thanks. I was wondering how Except[] can be used there. I saw `Except[]` used in `Cases` but not in `Replace` in the help pages.

Comment: Since you want to test for the presence of `x` anywhere in the prefactor to `c`, I don't thing `Except` is going to be of much use here. I can't think of a pattern that would match any expression that contains an `x` somewhere without using `FreeQ` or `MemberQ` as conditions. The problem here is that you're trying to find `x` at any level of the expression, so you'll have to use `FreeQ` or `MemberQ` in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tweak of @Coolwater's answer in his comments:

```
ReplaceAll[
    {Exp[c], Exp[5 c], Exp[y c], Exp[x c], Exp[Sin[x] c]},
    Exp[Optional[_?(FreeQ[x])] c] :> c
]
```

> {c, c, c, E^(c x), E^(c Sin[x])}